# Incomprehensible problem with split-environment in beamer documents

Tags: beamer, equations, align, split

In a set of slides I am creating with `beamer class`, I want to use the split environment to align wrapped equations (see example below).

My problem is, that `latexmk` throws an error `*Missing { inserted* at line`, which I fail to understand. If I change the `documentclass` to `*article*` and uncomment the beamer-specific commands the pdf is created without any problem.

Can anyone explain to me the mistake I made or the pitfall I ran into, as I am not aware of any limitations with regards to equations in beamer class.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\raTab}[1]{{\textsf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\raCol}[1]{\textsf{#1}}

\newcommand{\semijoin}{\displaystyle\mathop{\rhd\hspace{-6pt}<}}
\newcommand{\antisemijoin}{\displaystyle\mathop{\overline{\semijoin}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Lorem ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\pi_\raCol{attr1}&(\sigma_{\raCol{attr2} = \textit{‘val1‘}} (\raTab{REL1})\\
&\antisemijoin_{(\raCol{attr1})} \sigma_{\raCol{attr3 = 'val2'} \ \vee \ \raCol{attr3 = 'val3'}}(\raTab{REL2}))
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first term should be `\pi_{\raCol{attr1}}` (i.e. you should brace the argument of the subscript), or better you should better use `\mathsf` instead of `\textsf` in the definition of `\raCol`. Then it will work both with `article` and `beamer`. (But bracing is better anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lessons learned:

- always enclose the arguments of subscripts and superscripts in braces
- use the commands from *amsmath* to format text inside equations (e.g. `\mathsf` instead of `\textsf`, `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf`,...)

Thank you for your help, *campa*.